# how to authenticate the user and admin in the nest js, how to use the jwt strategy sepperately for both?

Tags: jwt, nestjs, client, admin, role-base-authorization

can i get assistance in user and admin jwt authentication, i have given two jwt strategies for admin and user, the default strategy was given as 'jwt', my client jwt token and authentication works properly the authguard protects the routes, but the same implementation not working for admin. the admin token is not authenticating instead the call goes to the client strategy and client token can be used to get the data of the damin route.

PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),

can we give jwt strategy something else, like for admin admin-jwt and for client client-jwt?

```
@Module({
  controllers: [
    StudentsController,
    AdminAuthController,
  ],
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.register({
      global: true,
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET_ADMIN,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRE_ADMIN },
    }),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Admin', schema: adminSchema }]),
  ],
  providers: [
    adminJwtStrategy,
    AdminAuthService,
    AdminJwtAuthGuard,
    ClientService,
    JwtService
  ],
  exports: [
    AdminAuthService,
    ClientService,
    AdminJwtAuthGuard
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.register({
      global: true,
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET_CLIENT,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRE_CLIENT },
    }),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Client', schema: clientSchema }]),
  ],
  controllers: [
    ClientAuthController,
    ProfileController
  ],
  providers: [
    ClientAuthService,
    ClientJwtStrategy,
    JwtService
  ],
  exports: [ClientJwtStrategy, PassportModule],
})
export class ClientModule { }
```

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientModule,
    AdminModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: ".env",
      isGlobal: true
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
  ],
  providers: [JwtService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```